# Change window control value using a Command

Tags: wpf

I need to change label value when clicking on a button so it will say "Please wait".

That button have a command, but since the command doesn't know the window controls I can't refer to them from the command.

For a reference, this is the label:

```
<Label Content="{Binding EuroCurrentRate}" Margin="450,226,672,351" x:Name="EurLabel" Foreground="White"  FontSize="22" >
```

And this the command :

```
    class EuroClickCommand : ICommand
{


  public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var viewModel = (RTViewModel)parameter;

        viewModel.OpenGraph();// When button is pushed fire this function
    } 

}
```

The property in the ViewModel:

```
    public ICommand ButtonClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new EuroClickCommand();
        }
    }

    public void OpenGraph()//Fire commands by button binding and command mechanism
    {

        AreaChart.MainWindow myWindow = new AreaChart.MainWindow();
        myWindow.Show();


    }
```

How should I change the label content from the command ?

Answer (score 0):

Label has binding to a viewmodel property:

```
<Label Content="{Binding EuroCurrentRate}" .../>
```

change that property in command method:

```
public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var viewModel = (RTViewModel)parameter;
    viewModel.EuroCurrentRate = "Please wait";
    viewModel.OpenGraph();// When button is pushed fire this function
}
```

or more likely `EuroCurrentRate = "Please wait";` should be done in OpenGraph() method